# bsearch not searching entire array passed to it

Tags: c, arrays, binary-search, bsearch

I am having trouble with this bsearch. Im pretty sure that I've isolated the problem to the number of bytes parameter that bsearch takes in. The data array is a scrabble dictionary and I'm 100% sure that the entire dictionary is loaded into memory, but when I use bsearch to try to find if a particular word is in the dictionary, it only works for words before 'wontedly' even though the dictionary's last word is 'zzz' so some words starting with 'w' 'x' 'y' and 'z' are not able to be found. It's almost as if the bsearch function can not see the end of the array, even though it's there. Another thing of note is that in my comparison function i print out what bsearch has passed to it to see what words are being compared, and it seems that on the first comparison, bsearch does not send the middle value which is something like 'lunkheads', instead, it is starting at 'lodge' which is not the middle word in the dictionary. 16 bytes is the number I put in, through trial and error that seems to work. The issue is that I do not know what the length of each element in the array is, or at least I think that's the issue.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LEN 128


 int search(const void *usr_word,const void *words);

struct data_t {
    int nval;       /* current number of values in array */
    int max;        /* allocated number of values */
    char **data;        /* the data array */
};

enum {INIT = 1, GROW = 2};

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("scrabble.txt", "r");
    assert(fp);
    char *usr_word = NULL;
    char buf[LEN];
    int i = 0;
    char number[LEN];
    char* item = NULL;


    struct data_t *data = malloc(sizeof(struct data_t));
    data->nval = INIT;
    data->max = INIT;
    data->data = NULL;
    while (fgets(buf, LEN, fp)) {
            if (data->data == NULL) {
                    data->data = malloc(strlen(buf) - 1);
                    assert(data->data);
            }
            else if (data->nval > data->max) {
                    data->data = realloc(data->data, GROW * data->max * LEN);
                    assert(data->data);
                    data->max = GROW * data->max;
            }

            data->data[i] = strndup(buf, strlen(buf) - 1);
            i++;
            data->nval++;
    }
    /* overcounted */
    data->nval--;
    printf("Enter word: ");
    fgets(buf, LEN, stdin);
    usr_word = strndup(buf, strlen(buf)-1);

    /*search for word*/
    item = (char *) bsearch(usr_word, data->data[0], data->nval, 16, search);
    if (item != NULL) 
           printf("\n%s is valid\n", item);
    else if (item == NULL)
           printf("\n%s is not valid\n", usr_word);

    return 0;
}

int search(const void *usr_word,const void *words)
{      
 printf("%s | %s | %d\n", (char *)usr_word,(char *)  words, strcmp(usr_word,words));
    return strcmp(usr_word,words);
}
```

Comment: Please prepare a minimal working example of your problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example). Get rid of everything that isn't necessary to reproduce your problem, things like user interaction etc.

Comment: is your data sorted? bsearch only works on sorted data.

Comment: I'll get a minimal working example up, but yes, the dictionary is sorted to start with

Comment: @fukanchik yes the data is sorted.

Comment: hmmm - I think The 2nd arg in `search()` should point to an element of `words`.  I suspect that would be a `char**` in your case.  2) What is 16 about?

Comment: Assertions are for verifying invariants of your program.  That is, an assertion says "I have committed a programming error if this condition is false at this point."  Do not use them to test error conditions that may arise despite your program being correct, for the whole point is that the whole thing can be altogether removed depending on how you compile the program, asserted expression and all.

Comment: regarding the calls to strlen():  the returned value from strlen() is the number of bytes before the string terminator byte.  You actually want to copy the string terminator byte, so instead of 'strlen() -1'  it should be 'strlen() +1'

Comment: regarding the calls to realloc(): the returned value must be checked (!=NULL) before assigning to the target pointer.  Otherwise all following references to offsets from the target pointer will actually be to offsets from address 0 (which is undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event) and the original pointer is lost, resulting in a memory leak.

Comment: all pointers returned by strndup() must be (eventually) passed to free().  otherwise memory leaks will result.

Comment: in C, a void * will automatically be set to the right type when assigned to some pointer,  so, as with malloc and family, the returned value should not be cast.

Comment: in the char ** array, the offset between the successive pointers to the data->data[] is only the width of a char *, (4 or 8 bytes depending the system being 32 or 64 bits.  so the '16' parameter to bsearch() should be sizeof(char*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, there are multiple problems with your code all originating from your misunderstanding of `char **` which is used in struct data_t.data.

`char **` is array of pointers to pointers. it is not array of strings in any way.

This means the following:

```
data->data = malloc(strlen(buf) - 1);
```

should be  replaced with the following:

```
data->data = malloc(sizeof(char *) * (data->nval));
```

same with `realloc`:

```
data->data = realloc(data->data, GROW * data->max * LEN);
```

replace with

```
data->data = realloc(data->data, GROW * data->max * sizeof(char *));
```

next, bsearch invocation:

```
item = (char *) bsearch(usr_word, data->data[0], data->nval, 16, search);
```

replace with:

```
item = (char **) bsearch(usr_word, data->data, data->nval, sizeof(char*), search);
```

see how i replaced 16 with sizeof(char*)? this is because `bsearch` is applied to `char **`, e.g. array of `char *`, hence, elementary bsearch item is `char *`. Hence, return value from `bsearch` is `pointer to elementary item, e.g. pointer to`char *`, e.g.`char **`.

quote from manpage:

> The bsearch() function returns a pointer to a matching member of the array

next is printf:

```
printf("\n%s is valid\n", item);
```

i replacing with:
    printf("\n%s is valid\n", *item);

`*item` instead of `item` is due to the same reason - bsearch returns us pointer to what it have found. We need to resolve this pointer into real value.

And finally your `search`:

```
printf("%s | %s | %d\n", (char *)usr_word,(char *)  words, strcmp(usr_word,words));
return strcmp(usr_word,words);
```

again, use correct level of pointers - we have two-level and we need one-level:

```
printf("%s | %s | %d\n", (char *)usr_word,*(char **)  words, strcmp(usr_word,words));
return strcmp(usr_word,*(char**)words);
```

For your convinience, here's the whole program which works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LEN 128

int search(const void *usr_word,const void *words);

struct data_t {
    int nval;       /* current number of values in array */
    int max;        /* allocated number of values */
    char **data;        /* the data array */
};

enum {INIT = 1, GROW = 2};

int main(void)
{
FILE *fp = fopen("scrabble.txt", "r");
assert(fp);
char *usr_word = NULL;
char buf[LEN];
int i = 0;
char number[LEN];
char** item = NULL;


struct data_t *data = malloc(sizeof(struct data_t));
data->nval = INIT;
data->max = INIT;
data->data = NULL;
while (fgets(buf, LEN, fp)) {
        if (data->data == NULL) {
                data->data = malloc(sizeof(char *) * (data->nval));
                assert(data->data);
        }
        else if (data->nval > data->max) {
                data->data = realloc(data->data, GROW * data->max * sizeof(char *));
                assert(data->data);
                data->max = GROW * data->max;
        }

        data->data[i] = strndup(buf, strlen(buf) - 1);
        i++;
        data->nval++;
}
/* overcounted */
data->nval--;
printf("Enter word: ");
fgets(buf, LEN, stdin);
usr_word = strndup(buf, strlen(buf)-1);

/*search for word*/
item = (char **) bsearch(usr_word, data->data, data->nval, sizeof(char*), search);
if (item != NULL)
       printf("\n%s is valid\n", *item);
else if (item == NULL)
       printf("\n%s is not valid\n", usr_word);

for(i=0;i<data->nval;++i) free(data->data[i]);
free(data->data);
free(data);
free(usr_word);

return 0;
}

int search(const void *usr_word,const void *words)
{
 printf("%s | %s | %d\n", (char *)usr_word,*(char **)  words,     strcmp(usr_word,words));
    return strcmp(usr_word,*(char**)words);
}
```

Comment: "`char **` is array of pointers to pointers. it is not array of strings in any way."  Not so.  `char **` is *a* pointer to a pointer, not an array of them. It may represent an array of pointers (to `char`).  Inasmuch as the elements of such an array may be pointers to the first elements of strings, it is entirely plausible that such a value represents an array of strings.

Comment: With that said, however, there's a lot of good analysis and advice in this answer.